# Get a custom matrix from Euro Stoxx 50 (SX5E) in R

Tags: r, import

I would like to know if there is a way to get a custom way to import stock data into R

For instance I want to get the following matrix of the stock  Euro Stoxx 50  :

```
Stock1  Day1    OpenPriceDay1   ClosePriceDay1
Stock1  Day2    OpenPriceDay2   ClosePriceDay2
...     ...     ...             ...
Stock1  Day_n   OpenPriceDay_n  ClosePriceDay_n

...     ...     ...             ...

Stock50 Day1    OpenPriceDay1   ClosePriceDay1
Stock50 Day2    OpenPriceDay2   ClosePriceDay2
...     ...     ...             ...
Stock50 Day_n   OpenPriceDay_n  ClosePriceDay_n
```

Where I could choose day1 and day_n

I've tried the package `quantmod` but it's not recognizing the SX5E Symbol...

PS: Of course I'm also open to get a csv with another method and import it later in R if it's easier.

Comment: `SX5E` is a Bloomberg ticker. You can try `^STOXX50E` or `FEZ` (the latter being an ETF) when downloading data from yahoo with the `quantmod` package.

Comment: Hello, I've tried getSymbols("^STOXX50E") but I only get the Index. My aim is to get the value of each of the 50 shares (not the index itself...)

Comment: Aha. [This](http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2012/07/17/factor-attribution-to-improve-performance-of-the-1-month-reversal-strategy/) software package has a function to retrieve the _actual_ S&P500 index constituents (see the line `tickers = sp500.components()$tickers`). Maybe there is something for the Stoxx 50 as well... However, as far as I know it does not include a function to fetch _historical_ constituent weights.